# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter shows first row when adding a new DB entry

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I'm using a custom SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a listView. When I add a new entry in the table, the list view adds the first DB entry to the end of the ListView.
Why does it insert the first row and not the last one?

I guess it's an update issue because when restarting the app, the list view shows all rows correctly.

I'm using the special cursor adapter to alternate colors of each row. If I simply use the SimpleCursorAdapter, it all works fine.

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {


private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitle;
    TextView mDate;
    String mDateString;
    TextView mCountDown;
    String mCountDownString;
}

private int[] colors = new int[] { 0xAAf6ffc8, 0xAA538d00 };
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String[] data;

public SpecialAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
 public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID) {
        long ms = Long.parseLong(text);
        Date date = new Date(ms);
        String formatedText = date.toString();
                 //do format
        super.setViewText(v, formatedText);

    } else {
        super.setViewText(v, text);
    }
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)  {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    int colorPos = cursor.getPosition() % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    holder.mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
    int col = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
    holder.mTitle.setText(cursor.getString(col));
    holder.mTitle.setTag(holder);

    col = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_DATE);
    Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(col));
    holder.mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID);
    holder.mDate.setText(date.toString());
    holder.mDateString = date.toString();
    holder.mDate.setTag(holder);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    long diff = cal.getTimeInMillis() - date.getTime();
    Date diffDate = new Date(diff);
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    holder.mCountDown = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countdownID); 
    holder.mCountDown.setText(timeFormat.format(diffDate));
    holder.mCountDownString = timeFormat.format(diffDate);
    holder.mCountDown.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View convertView, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    if(holder != null) {
        int col = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
        holder.mTitle.setText(cursor.getString(col));
        int colorPos = cursor.getPosition() % colors.length;
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        holder.mDate.setText(holder.mDateString);
        holder.mCountDown.setText(holder.mCountDownString);

    }
}
```

Comment: any ideas? Please let me know if the question isn't clear or if I need to add more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now:
The problem was that I tagged the wrong views:
I removed all setTag(...) code in newView() and set the tag only once:

```
 view.setTag(holder)
```

before returning it.